# Take value of the child of a child of a child in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to observe this value:
[image]

With this code:
[image]

But this give me error. I tried many times with other database methods like make value1 in a single child divided by value 2.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. Also include the error that you get and where you get it. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ref2.child("keywords").child("hello").child("hello").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    guard
        let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any],
        let value1 = dict["value1"] as? Int
    else { print("Error"); return }

    print(value1)

})
```

> Next time paste your code as text, not as an image

Comment: still prints Error

Comment: @cisc0 Try adding `print(snapshot.value)` immediately after the first line (before the `guard`) and tell me what you see into the console

Comment: <null> and then Error

Comment: @cisc0 How are you creating `ref2`?

Comment: ref2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

Comment: It's correct. Maybe there's a problem with the connection to firebase.

Comment: Are you sure `keywords` is NOT inside another node in firebase?

Comment: sure, I explain you what I would like to do.

Comment: I have 5 buttons. Each button when pressed change the value inside adding 1 to the actual value. I would like to observe inside for taking in realtime the values so then I can use the numbers for a bar chart

Comment: And your code for updating the values is working already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146955/discussion-between-appzyourlife-and-cisc0).

Comment: hey @appzYourLife